# How to serialize form with viewmodel and table content?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am new in ASP.NET MVC. I am facing a issue and unable to find the solution. Actually i am creating an Inventory Management project. In this project i have 2 ViewModels. One is PurchaseOrderViewModel and another one is TableViewModel. Now i am using both in a popup modal and save the details in there viewmodel but i am unable to do that. In the image you can see that there is a table record showing in the below which i need to insert in the view model. Please help me in this. I am really thankful to you.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateOrUpdatePurchase(PurchaseOrderViewModel purchase)
    {
        PurchaseOrder purchase2 = new PurchaseOrder();
        int suplierId = purchase.Supplier_ID;
        purchase.Supplier_ID = suplierId;
        purchase.SupplierName = context.Suppliers.Where(x => x.Supplier_ID == suplierId).Select(x => x.Supplier_Name).FirstOrDefault();
        string loginId = Convert.ToString(Session["LoginId"]);
        string UserRoleName = Convert.ToString(Session["UserTypeName"]);
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginId))
            {
                if (UserRoleName == RoleTypeConstant.CustomerUserType)
                {
                    PurchaseOrder purchase1 = new PurchaseOrder();
                    purchase1.LoginID = loginId;
                    purchase1.PurchaseID = purchase.PurchaseID;
                    purchase1.SupplierID = purchase.Supplier_ID;
                    purchase1.SupplierName = purchase.SupplierName;
                    purchase1.Currency = purchase.Currency;
                    purchase1.Date_Of_Purchase = purchase.Date_Of_Purchase;
                    purchase1.Due_Date = purchase.Due_Date;
                    purchase1.CreatedBy = loginId;
                    purchase1.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                    purchase1.UpdatedBy = loginId;
                    purchase1.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                    purchase1.Status = StatusConstant.Active;
                    bool regCustBen = await _websiteRepo.AddPurchase(purchase1);
                    if (regCustBen)
                    {
                        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("GetPurchasePartial");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Purchase_Order", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }


public class TableViewModel 
{

    public int Pid { get; set; }
    //public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }

}

public class PurchaseOrderViewModel
{
    public int PurchaseID { get; set; }
    public string LoginID { get; set; }

    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public int Supplier_ID { get; set; }

    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string Supplier_Name { get; set; }

    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public string Date_Of_Purchase { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public string Due_Date { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    //public List<Order> s { get; set; }

    public int Stock_ID { get; set; }
    public string Stock_Name { get; set; }

    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public List<TableViewModel> TableListDto  { get; set; }
}
```

My Script is

```
    function CreateOrUpdate() {
        debugger;
        var modal = $("#purchaseModal");
        var form = $('form[name="purchaseForm"]');

        let tableData = $('#detailsTable > tbody > tr');
        debugger;
        console.log(tableData);

        var tableDto = [];

        $.each(tableData, function (rindex, row) {
            console.log(row);

            let tmp = {};

            tmp.pid = $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').attr('pid');
            //tmp.productName = $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
            tmp.qty = $(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            tmp.price = $(row).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
            tmp.amount = $(row).find('td:nth-child(4)').text();

            tableDto.push(tmp);
            tmp = {};
        });



        form.validate();
        if (!form.valid()) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            var data = form.serialize();
            //data.TableListDto = tableDto.serialize();
            $.post("/Home/CreateOrUpdatePurchase", data, function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    modal.modal('hide');
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    $.notify("Saved Successfully", {
                        className: "success",
                        globalPosition: 'top - center'
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Let me show you my output screen. [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQlAf.png)

Comment: don't use `nth-child(1)` type things, give the `td` a class for use - so you can move columns around for example and not have to redo logic.

Comment: validate `purchase` before you use it in your method

Comment: `purchase.Supplier_ID = suplierId;`? why? this makes no sense to me to have a confusing `Supplier_ID` and `SupplierID`

Comment: Hi Mark, If i remove the nth-child(1) then how can i get the values in the table. Can you provide me correct code for this. and please look in the output screen i have just uploaded in my post.

Comment: Mark, That is used for the dropdown values coming from the Supplier Table to save the values in the viewmodel.

Comment: Show your view (and partial view I would hope you use), but basically either use an `input` element or, set a class on like `<td class="quantity">12345<td>` then `$(row).find('.quantity').text();` or put the value in a data ` `<td class="quantity" data-value="12345>12345 fish<td>`  `qty = $(row).find('.quantity').data('value');`

Comment: More important to your question, you have `tableDto` but never use it?  Are you attempting to post  back one or a list of `PurchaseOrderViewModel` without your view(s) it is hard to tell

Comment: Mark I have already shared a screenshot of my page. You can see that

Comment: tableDto is used earlier but through this i am not getting output that's why i have marked it as a comment.

Comment: Please help me in this Mark.

Comment: @Mark you want to see my view page. Please confirm this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to post your list of purchases, this is somewhat fabricated and contrived example but should show you the basic porting in the c# and the core save part in `savePurchases` function in the namespace.  I wrote this pretty fast and did not test this past very basic (and no c# test) so there may be some typos etc.

For this you only need to pay attention to two things

1. the model to save (a list of these)
2. the object sent to that save cart method (array matching that) see the `savePurchases` function

I made a form to work with, putting items in the cart (did not add a remove), the cart being the `purchases` object array in the namespace.  This has only simple "add an item" with no super fancy stuff in it.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> CreateOrUpdatePurchase(List<SaveModel> purchase)
{
    // first validate your data here
    // second, call your middle ware code to update database
    // third return results back, whatever you need, I made this up
    return Json(
         new PurchaseResultModel
         {
              PurchaseQuantity = somevalue,
              PurchaseValue = somemoney,
              /*These are Provider only options.*/
              SavedOK = true, //verify save OK
              ValidData = true // validated data OK
          });
 }
public class SaveModel 
{
    public int Pid { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Create some JSON to send back

```js
var myApp = {
  products: [{
    pid: "123",
    name: "Water Cats",
    price: 42.34
  }, {
    pid: "32234",
    name: "Bolts",
    price: 1.18
  }, {
    pid: "56",
    name: "Sheep",
    price: 34.34
  }, {
    pid: "2323",
    name: "Sack - cotton",
    price: 5.99
  }],
  currency: 'USD',
  currencySymbol: '$',
  onAddProduct: function() {
    let productCart = $('#product-cart');
    let firstProductItem = productCart
      .find('.product-item')
      .first();

  },
  prod: {},
  savePurchases: function(event) {
    let me = event.data[0].arg1;
    if (me.purchases.length > 0) {
      // get what we sold
      let purchases = [];
      // this just to show how to make a match to the c# class
      // I left out price and amount since that should be a server calculation to prevent hacking of values.
      for (var i = 0; i < me.purchases.length; i++) {
        let p = {
          Pid: me.purchases[i].pid,
          Qty: me.purchases[i].qty
        };
        purchases.push(p);
      }

      $.ajax({
          url: "/Home/SavePurchase",
          data: purchases,
        })
        .complete(function(res) {
          if (res) {
            modal.modal('hide');
            dataTable.ajax.reload();
            $.notify("Saved Successfully", {
              className: "success",
              globalPosition: 'top - center'
            });
          }
        })
        .fail(function(x) {
          // save fail action
        });
    } else {
      // tell them they made no selections?
    }
  },
  validate: function() {
    form.validate();
    if (!form.valid()) {
      return;
    } else {
      //do valid thing
    }
  },
  onQuantityChange: function(event) {
    let me = event.data[0].arg1;
    if (this.value > 0) {
      let opt = me.productSelect.find("option:selected");
      let product = opt.data('item');
      $('#price').val(product.price);
      let a = me.roundToCents(product.price * $(this).val());
      me.setFieldAmount(a, $('#amount-sold')[0]);
    } else {
      $('#price').val(0);
      me.setFieldAmount(0, $('#amount-sold')[0]);
    }
  },
  localStringToNumber: function(s) {
    return Number(String(s).replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, ""));
  },
  setFieldAmount: function(amount, field) {
    var options = {
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
      currency: this.currency,
      style: "currency",
      currencyDisplay: "symbol"
    };
    field.value = amount ?
      this.localStringToNumber(amount).toLocaleString(undefined, options) :
      '';
  },
  setTextAmount: function(amount, field) {
    var options = {
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
      currency: this.currency,
      style: "currency",
      currencyDisplay: "symbol"
    };
    let v =
      amount ?
      this.localStringToNumber(amount).toLocaleString(undefined, options) :
      '';
    field.text(v);
  },
  onProductChange: function(event) {
    let me = event.data[0].arg1;
    let opt = me.productSelect.find("option:selected");
    let hasSelection = !!opt;
    me.productSelect.toggleClass('choice-made', hasSelection);
    let q = $('#quantity');
    q.prop('disabled', !hasSelection)
      .val(hasSelection ? 1 : 0)
      .trigger('change');
  },
  roundToCents: function(num) {
    return Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
  },
  onAddItem: function(event) {
    let me = event.data[0].arg1;
    let prod = me.productSelect;
    // only if we made a valid choice
    if (prod.hasClass('choice-made')) {
      let optVal = prod.find("option:selected").val();
      let product = me.products.find(x => x.pid === optVal);
      if (product) {
        let q = $('#quantity');
        let cart = $('#product-cart');
        let first = cart.find('.product-item').first();
        let itemRowC = first.clone();
        itemRowC.find('.product-name').text(product.name);
        itemRowC.find('.product-quantity').text(q.val());
        me.setTextAmount(product.price, itemRowC.find('.product-price').first());
        me.setTextAmount($('#amount-sold').val(), itemRowC.find('.product-amount').first());
        let v = {
          pid: optVal,
          qty: q.val()
        };
        me.purchases.push(v);
        itemRowC.find('.hidden').find('div').unwrap('.hidden');
        let calctot = cart.find('.grand-total-group');
        itemRowC.insertBefore(calctot);
        let total = me.getCalculatedTotal(me.purchases);
        // reset quantity values
        q.prop('disabled', true)
          .val(0)
          .trigger('change');
        prod.val('')
          .removeClass('choice-made');
      }
    }
  },
  getCalculatedTotal: function(purchases) {
    let total = 0;
    let count = purchases.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < purchases.length; i++) {
      let product = this.products.find(x => x.pid === purchases[i].pid);
      total = total + (product.price * purchases[i].qty);
    }
    $('.products-in-cart').text(count);
    this.setTextAmount(total, $('#grand-total'));
    return total;
  },
  startup: function() {
    this.productSelect = $('#products');
    this.purchases = [];
    //add products
    this.products.forEach(product => {
      const opt = $('<option value="' + product.pid + '">' + product.name + '</option>');
      opt.data('item', product);
      this.productSelect.append(opt);
    });
    $('#quantity').on('change', [{
      arg1: this
    }], this.onQuantityChange);
    $('#products').on('change', [{
      arg1: this
    }], this.onProductChange);
    $('#add-to-cart').on('click', [{
      arg1: this
    }], this.onAddItem);
    $('#save-cart').on('click', [{
      arg1: this
    }], this.savePurchases);
  }
};

myApp.startup();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="purchaseModal">
  <div id="purchaseOptions" data-list="[]" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
          <span class="text-muted">Your cart</span>
          <span class="products-in-cart badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
        </h4>
        <ul id="product-cart" class="list-group mb-3">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed product-item">
            <div class="hidden">
              <div>
                <h6 class="my-0">Product name</h6>
                <small class="text-muted product-name">Brief description</small>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h6 class="my-0">Quantity</h6>
                <small class="text-muted product-quantity">3</small>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h6 class="my-0">Price</h6>
                <small class="text-muted product-price">$12.24</small>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h6 class="my-0">Amount</h6>
                <small class="centered-text text-muted product-amount">$36.72</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="grand-total-group list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
            <div class="text-success">
              <span>Total (USD)</span>
            </div>
            <strong class="text-success"><span id="grand-total">0</span></strong>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 order-md-1">
        <h4 class="mb-3">Choose Products</h4>
        <form class="product-choice needs-validation" novalidate="" _lpchecked="1">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
              <label for="products">Products</label>
              <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="products" required="">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
              </select>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please select a valid Product.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-3 ">
              <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">#</span>
                </div>
                <input type="number" disabled="true" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="0" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
                  Quantity is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 ">
              <label for="price">Price</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" disabled="true">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 ">
              <label for="amount-sold">Amount</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$" class="form-control" id="amount-sold" disabled="true">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 ">
            <button id="add-to-cart" class="form-control btn btn-info btn-sm " type="button">Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="sm-4">
      <button id="save-cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" type="button">Save Cart</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i got my answer how to do this. Thanks a ton!!!!